# Sublime Text not showing up in 17.10 fresh install

Tags: software-installation, sublime-text

I've just moved to 17.10 from .04 and cannot get sublime text to install properly.

If i install the package sublime-text-installer I get version 3126 and it complains about upgrading whenver I start it.

If I follow [this method](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html) I get 3143 in the console, but then I cannot find or launch Sublime Text at all, it's missing from the Applications list.

I haven't noticed any other apps missing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didnt specify which DM you have (gdm kdm lxdm)
if you are on lxdm/lubuntu > terminal

```
rm ~/.cache/menus/* 
lxpanelctl restart
```

to find your .desktop file > terminal as root

```
updatedb
locate <your.app.name> | grep -i desktop
```

should point to a .desktop file inside /usr/share/applications/; that file contains the group to which the program is assigned; my guess it should be assigned to programming group

Comment: Sorry, I'm running vanilla Ubuntu 17.10 x64 Desktop. I found the .desktop file with that but found that sublime is simply broken when installed via 'sublime-text' rather than 'sublime-text-installer'. That's why it's the only app I've installed not to show up. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Also, I didn't have lxpanelctl installed prior, but since it didn't change anything I have removed it.

Comment: @user688056 I am facing the same problem and first two commands doesn't work for me, the directory doesn't exist for me and lxpanelctl is not installed. Although I can locate the installation and open it directly from there or using your last command to locate the shortcut but, still the program is not listing in the programs list and cannot be found using gnome search, any idea about how I can do that please ? Also, I have done multiple clean installation of sublime but that doesn't help. :(. Appreciate your help.

Comment: ive tested the method for 3143 linked by noky on ubuntu live 17.10 inside a virtualbox and it works fine; in any case you should have a sublime.desktop file inside /usr/share/applications/; ps: ubuntu live 17.10 crashes like theres no tomorrow inside virtualbox 5.1 ive barely managed to finish the test